# Add propertyA if propertyB of objects match

Tags: javascript

I want to add propertyA if propertyB of objects matches

**Before**

```
 usa = [{fifa:"1", year:2000},{fifa:"3", year:2000},{fifa:"5", year:2010},{fifa:"2", year:2000},{fifa:"4", year:2010}];
```

**After**

```
usa = [{fifa:"6", year:2000},{fifa:"9", year:2010}];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a solution. Not very elegant but it works:

```
usa.reduce((acc, current) => {
  const f = acc.find(c => c.year == current.year)

  if (f) {
    f.fifa = parseInt(f.fifa, 10) + parseInt(current.fifa, 10)
  } else {
    acc.push({
      year: current.year,
      fifa: parseInt(current.fifa, 10).toString()
    })
  }
  return acc

}, [])
```

Comment: Why is this not elegant?

Comment: I don't like the `if` and the multiple `parseInt`. :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can verify the value of your array with `usa[index].fifa == "2"` 
 or `usa[index].year == 2000` and if it matches with some value, add a property via the [push()](https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) method

```
if (usa[index].year == 2000) {
  usa.push({fifa: "32", year: 2001})
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
     function add_propertyA_if_propertyB(array)
        {
            var arrayTmp = new Array();
            var arrayYears = new Array();
            for(int i=0;i<array.length;i++)
            {
               if(!arrayTmp[array[i].year]){
                arrayTmp[array[i].year] = array[i].fifa;
                arrayYears.push(array[i].year);
             }
               else
                arrayTmp[array[i].year] += array[i].fifa;
            }
           var arrayResult = new Array();
           for(int i=0;i<arrayYears.length;i++)
           {
              arrayResult.push(new {year:arrayYears[i], fifa:arrayTmp[arrayYears[i]]});
           }
           return arrayResult;
        }
```